# Joomla SQL drivers and prepared statements

Tags: database

Can you tell me if Joomla SQL drivers support prepared statements? As far as I understand, the MySQLi driver does not prepare SQL statements. But Joomla also supports MySQL PDO driver. Does this driver prepare SQL statements? Is it safe to use Joomla SQL wrappers?

Comment: Hello Mr. twister: Some time ago I came across a relative Google Groups discussion [**Prepared statement Support in Joomla**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-cms/fQEWk7Fn25c), which I think it's interesting.

Comment: @Elcero might you accept the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Prepared Statements are possible in Joomla 4

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$value = 'string';

$query->select($db->quoteName('something'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('foo') . ' = :myfield')
      ->bind(':myfield', $value);

$db->setQuery($query);

$records = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Some references:

- https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Moving_Joomla_To_Prepared_Statements
- [How to use prepared statements in Joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374054/2943403)
- [How to use prepare statements / bind values in a query in Joomla 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698230/2943403)