# loadObjectList() returns array indexed by empty string

Tags: database

Very simple query:

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('*')
        ->from('#__mail_templates')
        ->where('template_id = ' . $db->quote($this->getRowId()))
        ->where('language = ' . $db->quote($languageCode));
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList($query);
```

For some ungodly reason, $rows has index "", empty string. Using Joomla 4.2. I hope this is not intended behaviour??

var dump:

```
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  object(stdClass)#218 (14) {
    ["lang_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["asset_id"]=>
    int(66692)
    ["lang_code"]=>
    string(5) "de-DE"
    ...
```

Oh, I see now that the result is not coming from the correct table even.

```
#message: "Unknown fetch type '8'"
```

Comment: Was this the result set from the previously executed query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meh. Buggy line should be

```
$rows = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
```

A warning would have been nice...

Comment: A simple mistake like this is likely to bite other Joomlers; this is a good addition to our Q&A.

Comment: @mickmackusa Can't hurt. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can improve queries with prepared statements. As example:

```
$query = $db
    ->getQuery(true)
    ->select('*')
    ->from($db->qn('#__mail_templates'))
    ->where($db->qn('template_id') . ' = :getRowId')
    ->where($db->qn('language') . ' = :languageCode')
    ->bind(':getRowId', $this->getRowId())
    ->bind(':languageCode', $languageCode);
    
$db->setQuery($query);
        
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Moving_Joomla_To_Prepared_Statements

Comment: Oh Joomla supports this now? :D Only 15 years late.

Comment: More demos of parameter binding with Joomla's query building methods: [Attempt to assign property "team" on bool](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32124/12352) and [Joomla SQL drivers and prepared statements](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28513/12352) and [How to use prepared statements in Joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374054/2943403) and [How to use prepare statements / bind values in a query in Joomla 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698230/2943403) and [Is the following everything one should do to prevent SQL injection?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32136/12352)

Comment: Truth be told: `$db->q()` is incorrect/inappropriate when binding data.  The whole reason to use binding is to eliminate the need to quote/escape data.  The final `bind()` call should be `->bind(':languageCode', $languageCode);`

Comment: Sorry, copy & paste error. It's Fixed

Comment: Not only the answer I like here but from the comments we can learn too. Good. :)